# Error "command listCollections requires authentication" en Migrate Laravel 7 y MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, laravel-7

estoy haciendo un deploy de mi proyecto en ubuntu server 20.04 montado en una virtual >box, pero al realizar el migrate, me manda el siguiente error:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\CommandException
command listCollections requires authentication
```

Mi database.php:

```
'mongodb' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'host' => env('DB_MONGO_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_MONGO_PORT', 27017),
        'database' => env('DB_MONGO_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('DB_MONGO_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('DB_MONGO_PASSWORD'),
        'options' => [
            'database' => env('DB_MONGO_DATABASE') // sets the authentication database required by mongo 3
        ]
    ],
```

Mi .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
 
DB_MONGO_HOST=localhost
DB_MONGO_PASSWORD=
DB_MONGO_USER=
DB_MONGO_PORT=27017
DB_MONGO_DATABASE=sap-db
```

En local me funciona bien, pero en mi virtual box me da este error.. he intentado varias cosas pero sin resultado.. alguien puede orientarme?

Gracias de antemano..